# Why do we say, "where is the bathroom?" But, when we ask, "could you tell me where the bathroom is?" we end in a verb?

Tags: questions, modal-verbs

Ex without "could"

> where is the bathroom?

Ex with "could"

> Could you tell me where the bathroom is?

Ex with "could" improper use of "is"

> Could you tell me where is the bathroom

So why do we move the "is" when we use the "could"

Comment: "Could you tell me where is the bathroom" is not improper, it's just not idiomatic.

Comment: I used this on my test in class and the teacher told me it was wrong, but could not explain why. It is on our test which is reviewed by lots of professors

Comment: Embedded questions—questions within questions—do not undergo subject-verb inversion. See [Embedded Questions: Definition & Examples](https://www.learngrammar.net/english-grammar/embedded-questions).

Comment: You are asking for a piece of information - where the bathroom is.